# Image is not part of the body in HTML and made footer unable to be at the bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers, footer

I put an image in a div and somehow it's not part of the body thus made my footer unable to be at the bottom of the page. I read in here that i must make img position absolute, but it didn't change anything.

I just want my footer to be at the bottom of the page.

I tried to change the position of the image to be inside div and outside div, inside another div and so on, but still my footer wont go to the bottom.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text-box {
  padding-left: 55px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: georgia;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.flex-container img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.hedding-position {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.bakgrundsbilde {
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/856733.jpg";); /*bilde fra google */
  height: 675px;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

footer {
  line-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(28, 32, 36, 1);
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no">

<head>
  <title>Min website</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/meny.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/odin.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="bilder/favicon.ico">

  <style>
    body {}
    /*scrollbar utsene lånt ifra w3school. link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp */
    
     ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
    }
    
     ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: white;
    }
    
     ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
    
     ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!--bakgrundsbildet -->
  <div class="bakgrundsbilde"></div>

  <nav>
    <a href="home.html" style="background-color: lightgray; color: black;"> Hjem</a>
    <a href="profil.html"> Profil</a>
    <a href="faginteresse.html"> Faginteresse</a>
    <a href="fritidsinteresse.html"> Hobby</a>
    <a href="medier.html"> Verk</a>
    <a href="kontakt.html"> Kontakt</a>
    <a style="float:right;" href="#bunn">Til bunnen</a>
  </nav>

  <br>

  <!--skygen til bilde er tat ifra w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_shadows_box.asp-->
  <div class="flex-container">
    <img style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);" src="bilder/chair.jpg" alt="Odin" align="right">
    <div class="text-box">
      <div class="hedding-position">
        <h1 style="font-size: 50px; text-align: center; font-family: garamond;">Hei</h1>
      </div>
      <p>Jeg hetter Odin, jeg er student på informasjonsteknologi og mediaproduksjon. </p>
      <p>Detter er min personlige website som inkludærer min profil, faginteresse, hobbyer, medier og kontakt. </p>
      <p>Jeg bor på Sandnes her i Hadsel.</p>
      <p>Jeg flyttet tilbake etter å ha bodd på Høle i noen år.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <footer>
    This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.
  </footer>

  <!-- <footer id="bunn">

<p> copyright 2023</p>
</footer> -->

</body>

</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: give position: fixed; instead of relative to the footer

Comment: Do you want the footer fixed at the bottom of the viewport (e.g. always visible at the bottom of the screen) or do you want it at the bottom of the body, however high that is, or do you want it at the bottom of the viewport if the body is shorter than the viewport height and at the bottom of the body otherwise?

Comment: @MatiasBertoni i changed my css to fixed; but the there is no change at all.

Comment: @AHaworth I want my footer to be at the bottom at the page always. I dont want it to follow me around scrolling up and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code. regardless of the content, the footer must remain at the bottom

```
body {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-heigth: 100vh;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(28, 32, 36, 1);
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This changes the height of a short body, but I guess that is OK in many (if not most) circumstances so a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add `bottom: 0;` like this:

```
.flex-container img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /* Added */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Of course, that didn't work. Looking at the accepted answer, I see that I wasn't even targeting the footer. When I was answering your question, I looked at the code and `.flex-container img` was the only one with `position: absolute;`. Consequently, I suggested that you add `bottom: 0;` to the `.flex-container img`.

You set `position: relative;` to the `<footer>` which will not push the footer to the bottom no matter what you do. So, set `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` to the **footer(!)**. Also, set `position: relative;` to the parent element.

Comment: I tried this, but my footer still didn't move.

Comment: Please add more code. From the code you posted above, I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Alright, i will make it more readable and structured.

Comment: Edit: Person under this helped and made it work, thanks for your attempt to help.